# convert the list of items into dropdown list knockout js

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-validation, knockout-3.0

I'm new to knockout. May I know how should I convert this unordered list of items into dropdown list with same databinding.

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
  <h4>Select a Request Reason:</h4>
   <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" data-bind="foreach: Reasons">
      <li role="presentation" data-bind="css: { 'active': Id() === $parent.Request().ReasonId() }">
       <a href="#" data-bind="text: Title(), click: $parent.SelectReason"></a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Id, Title and Description are the properties of dropdown list in model. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the [`options` binding](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html)?

Comment: thanks @user3297291

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `options` binding.

`<select data-bind="options: Reasons, optionsText: 'Title', optionsValue: 'Id', value: selectedReasonID, optionsCaption: 'Please select a reason'"></select>`

In this example you will need to add a selectedReasonID property to your viewmodel to store the selected ID. You could also store the entire Reason object if you needed to.